# Port is assessible though blocked by ufw

Tags: 18.10, ufw

I'm running a software listening port 31731. My client side software can connect to port 31731 on my server. Online port scan tool also confirms the port is open.

However, I check ufw status. The default rule is deny all incoming, and there is no rule allowing 31731.

```
~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY IN     83.237.17.0/24
Anywhere                   DENY IN     45.77.149.0/24
Anywhere                   DENY IN     178.159.37.0/24
Anywhere                   DENY IN     37.115.223.0/24
Anywhere                   DENY IN     207.180.255.0/24
Anywhere                   DENY IN     42.117.48.0/24
Anywhere                   DENY IN     213.152.162.0/24
Anywhere                   DENY IN     5.227.15.0/24
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
123/udp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
123/udp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

~$
```

Why is the port accessible? Could the server side software override ufw, or is ufw not configured properly?